# android list view jump to a selected item

Tags: android, listview

I have an application where I have one edittext. And also I have one listview that is populated with 100 items and can show only 5 items at a time. I enter a number (n) in the Edittext and I want listview to jump to the n th item of the list view

Comment: please add your code and explain your needs

Comment: listView.smoothScrollToPosition(position) this method might help you

Comment: i think you want search filter right?

Comment: listView.smoothScrollToPosition(position) is working

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 EditText edi=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.youredittext);
    edi.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

       @Override
       public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {}
             int pos=Integer.parseInt(s.toString());
             listView.smoothScrollToPosition(pos); //use to scroll to this position
       @Override    
       public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
         int count, int after) {
       }

       @Override    
       public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
         int before, int count) {

       }
      });
```